# Spring MVC : produces is not working on controller method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc and now trying to learn controllers. During the controller creation i just tried using produces on the controller method. But unfortunately the method is not invoked. The code and screen shot is attached.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method6", produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String method6(){
    return "method6";
}

@RequestMapping("**")
@ResponseBody
public String fallbackMethod(){
    return "fallback method";
}
```

[image]

all requests from rest client calling fallbackmethod. so kindly help me to get out from the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the result if you call the url without the .htm at the end?

Comment: What happens if you omit `produces`? I don't like the idea of a fallback method. Calls to non-existing end points should just return the 404 code.

Comment: @Patrick : .htm is mapped on web.xml for url-pattern. so to find out the spring request its required here.

Comment: @Mohan Where did you take the screenshot from? What tool did you use?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, if i omit produces then the method call happened.

Comment: @Radu Ionescu : this is rest client jar.

Comment: Quite strange behaviour. It could have something to do with your url suffix. I would try replacing the `*.htm` for `*` in the url pattern and try to call just `/method6`. Also, do you have a JSON mapper as a dependency in your application? Spring needs it to do the JSON translation.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, yeah its working when i change the url-pattern to <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>. Kindly let me know what is the actual problem in technical..

Comment: Don't know exactly, you'll have to google it. However, I can infer the Spring framework is searching for a `method6.htm` view file which you don't have when you use the html suffix.